# Git - Delete commits where half changeset is valid and other half is invalid

Tags: git

So I did something stupid with a git project of mine. I accidentally committed and pushed a svg asset directory (~2000 svg files) that shouldn't have been checked into Git. I deleted the assets and then pushed again to remove it from the source code however I am not sure how to remove it from my git commit history.

- 17a3534 - Last valid commit
- 2129212 - Valid changes + Invalid SVG Directory
- 9c41416 - Deleted the Invalid SVG Directory

I'm not exactly sure how to fix this, I basically want to revert back to 17a3534  with the pending changes from 2129212 so I can delete the SVG directory and not have any of the .svg in the git commit history but keep the valid changes in the 2129212 commit.

Any ideas on how I would accomplish this?

If I can fix it locally I don't mind doing a force push and overriding the remote server.

[image: Messed up git]

Comment: _"I deleted the assets and then pushed again to remove it from the source code"_ - that is not how `git` works.

Comment: Run `git reset --soft 2129212`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the advice in [Dai's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74160130/git-delete-commits-where-half-changeset-is-valid-and-other-half-is-invalid#comment130935058_74160130):

```
git reset --soft 2129212
# at this point you'll have all of the svg files staged for deletion

git commit --amend
# now you'll rewrite this commit with only the valid files committed

git push --force-with-lease
```

**Side Note:** in Git, the word *revert* has a slightly different meaning than it does in English. Git `revert` will effectively undo a commit by creating a new commit that undoes the changes in the original commit. This is normally the preferred method of undoing changes because it enables you to push to a shared branch without re-writing it. The downside, as you've witnessed, is that it doesn't purge the history. If you wish to rewrite the history, instead of revert you would use for example `reset`, `rebase`, or amend a commit, all of which will usually require a force push afterwards.